# program that prints the result to linear equation of : ax+b = 0

Tags: java, if-statement, math, time

Is it possible to write less for example by writing the conditions into one if- instruction or something like that.My point is to cut the source code and find a better way to sum the informations in the if instruction up.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class LinGlj4u {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Bitte geben sie den Wert für a ein : ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Bitte geben sie den Wert für b ein : ");
        double b = input.nextDouble();

        double rechnung;
        if (a + b > 0) {
            rechnung = -b / a;
            System.out.println(rechnung);
        } else if (a + b < 0) {
            rechnung = +b / a;
            System.out.println(rechnung);
        } else if (a + b == 0 || a - b == 0) {
            System.out.println("x = 0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing @Jossef Harush

Comment: Could you post an [mcve] with all variables declared ?

Comment: Sorry, this is simply wrong.  The only check you need to make is whether or not a == 0; otherwise the solution is -b/a for all a and b.

Comment: But if the variables are negative there should ne a calculation too for example a= -5 b=-7 solution = -1.4 that's why i Put the Instruction of +b/a in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short version

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class LinGlj4u {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Bitte geben sie den Wert für a ein : ");
            double  a = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Bitte geben sie den Wert für b ein : ");
            double b = input.nextDouble();

            if(a != 0) {
                System.out.println("result is " +(-b/a));
            } else {
                System.out.println("result is infinity");
            }
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Would simplify it to the following

```
import java.util.*; 
public class LinGlj4u {

public static void main(String[] args) {        

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Bitte geben sie den Wert für a ein : ");
    double a = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Bitte geben sie den Wert für b ein : ");
    double b = input.nextDouble();

    if (a == 0) {
        System.out.println("x = 0");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(-b/a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is short enough for you. There's probably a better shorter way using Regex like Jossef showed in his example. The last else if condition isn't important so just making it else should do the trick as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // No need to ask twice, seperate inputs by space
    System.out.print("Bitte geben sie den Wert für a ein : ");
    Double a = input.nextDouble();
    Double b = input.nextDouble();
    Double rechnung;

    if (a != 0)
        rechnung = -b/a;
    else {
        System.out.println("x goes to infinity");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(rechnung);
}
```

Comment: @ duffymo  you are right, but the algebra is wrong in the question.

Comment: Exactly; why repeat the mistake in a bad answer?  Yours is correct, @c0der.

Comment: @duffymo: It is better to fix the algebra of course, but one should not expect  Matthew Zackschewski to answer math questions, but Java questions. I up  voted your comment on the question.

Comment: Thank you @c0der. I wasn't trying to correct his math, just simplify the code provided.

Comment: I disagree.  There is no simpler algebra problem.  A grammar school student should be able to get it right.  It's not tensor calculus; any educated person, programmer or non-programmer, should be able to solve it.

Comment: @ Matthew Zackschewski you may want to have another go and get an upvote

Comment: You've already successfully answered the question, algebra and all, so I would only be using what you wrote above as reference. I'll edit it for the sake of reputation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equation {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a Number");      
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter a Number ");      
        double b = input.nextDouble();

        if(a==0) {
            System.out.println("can not evaluate expression for a = 0 ");
        } else {
            double division = (b/a);
            double ans = -1 * division ;
            System.out.println(" Expression evaluation is " + ans);
        }

}
```

}